# Ruby NoMethodError (undefined method `set_body_internal') with HTTP get

Tags: ruby, nomethoderror

I am new to Ruby programming. I am trying to get the google XRDS with HTTP GET request, but running in to the NoMethodError (undefined method `set_body_internal') Error. Below is my code. Any help is much appreciated.

```
require "net/https"
require "uri"

class OpenidController < ApplicationController

  def getOpenIdXRD
    print "Hello...\n"
    uri = URI.parse("https://gmail.com/.well-known/host-meta")
    print "Hello...1\n"
    # Shortcut
    #response1 = Net::HTTP.get_response(uri)

    http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
    http.use_ssl = true
    http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
    print "Hello...2\n"
    File response1 = http.request(request)
    print "Hello...3\n"
    response1.body
    response1.status
    # Will print response.body
    # Net::HTTP.get_print(uri)  
  end

end
```

Here is my output:

```
Completed in 2ms (View: 1, DB: 72) | 200 OK [IP]
Hello...
Hello...1
Hello...2
tton]
  ←[4;36;1mSQL (188.1ms)←[0m   ←[0;1mSET SQL_AUTO_IS_NULL=0←[0m

Processing OpenidController#getOpenIdXRD (for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-06-25 20:28:04)
[GET]
  Parameters: {"user"=>""}

NoMethodError (undefined method `set_body_internal' for #):
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't actually assigned a value to the `request` parameter ...

```
response1 = http.request(request)
```

... also ...

```
File response1
```

... doesn't make much sense there - perhaps you want to write the result to a File?

Lastly, if you simply want to do a GET, something based on this should work for you ...

```
url = " ... insert valid path here ..."

res = Net::HTTP.start('... hostname here ...', 80) {|http|
  http.get(url)
}
puts res.body
```