# HTTPS request error: undefined method `set_body_internal'

Tags: ruby, ssl, https, request

The following code fails to execute:

```
require 'net/http'

uri = URI('https://example.com:8443')
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)

# Enable SSL/TLS ?
if uri.scheme == "https"
  http.use_ssl = true
  http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER
  http.ca_file = File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), "ca-rsa-cert.pem")
end

http.start {
  http.request(uri)
}
```

The error is:

```
$ ./TestCert.rb
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1292:in `request': undefined method `set_body_internal'
for #<URI::HTTPS:0x00000001a47fd0 URL:https://example.com:8443> (NoMethodError)
    from ./TestCert.rb:16:in `block in <main>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:745:in `start'
    from ./TestCert.rb:15:in `<main>'
```

Unlike [Ruby NoMethodError (undefined method `set_body_internal') with HTTP get](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17309815/ruby-nomethoderror-undefined-method-set-body-internal-with-http-get), I'm using HTTPS and I don't care about a response. I simply need Ruby to make the connection to test the SSL/TLS server.

I did try to capture a response per the related question, but that had the same error:

```
http.start {
  response = http.request uri
}
```

And this had the same error:

```
response = http.start {
  http.request uri
}
```

And `http.get` failed too (but with a different error - `undefined method 'empty?'`):

```
response = http.start {
  http.get uri
}
```

And another failure (but with a different error - `undefined method 'empty?'`):

```
http.start {
  response = http.get uri
}
```

If it matters, this is a Debian 7.3 (x64) system running Ruby 1.9.3p194.

How do I make a HTTP request over SSL/TLS using Ruby?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your call `http.request(uri)` is wrong, you should pass a kind of request object like `Net::HTTP::Get` instead of the `uri`. Try with the following code:

```
require 'net/http'

uri = URI('https://example.com:8443')
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)

# Enable SSL/TLS ?
if uri.scheme == "https"
  http.use_ssl = true
  http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER
  http.ca_file = File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), "ca-rsa-cert.pem")
end

req = Net::HTTP::Get.new('/')
http.request(req)
```

Or call directly [`request_get('/')`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html#method-i-request_get). That method will create the `Get` object for you, like the documentation explain:

```
def request_get(path, initheader = nil, &block) # :yield: +response+
  request(Get.new(path, initheader), &block)
end
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks. This was my first Ruby program. Its probably my last for a long time since I rarely need it. Thanks for tolerating the n00bness.

Comment: @noloader you are welcome! Why did you say that is your last Ruby program for long time?

Comment: I'm a C/C++/ObjC guy. I needed to test a C/C++ server against a Ruby client. I have no complaints with Ruby. I don't know the language, so I don't use it.

Comment: Rafa - here's where I got most of the code: [Verified HTTPS in Ruby](http://notetoself.vrensk.com/2008/09/verified-https-in-ruby/). I used it because it included the `ca_file`. But the last portion of code did not work. The last portion was in `http.start` block, and was `http.request_get(uri.path) {|res| print res.body }`. I guess Ruby is still too new, and its breaking itself as it matures.

Comment: Ruby has now more than 20 years. I know it for only 2 years but I really like it. Coding in Ruby is also fun, in my opinion. Of course is not going to be comparable in performance with C/C++ but usually it is used where this kind of performance is not critical.

Comment: "Ruby has now more than 20 years" - in that case, its been around long enough that it should not break itself between release ;)